# Xpath Not Returning Values lxml Python

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I'm working on a project and I'm trying to get lxml to pull stock data from separate tables on separate web pages. When I run my program trying to print the values I'm trying to pull I get empty brackets

```
('Cash_and_short_term_investments:', [])
('EPSNextYear:', [])
```

Here is a look at the way I am calling this:

```
  #the url at this point is http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=RAIL confirmed with print statement
   url = driver.current_url
   page2 = requests.get(url)
   tree2 = html.fromstring(page2.content)
   EPSNextYear =              
   tree2.xpath('/html/body/table[3]/tr[1]/td/table/tr[7]/td/table/tr[2]/td[6]/b')
   #Original XPath:/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[6]/b
   print ('EPSNextYear:', EPSNextYear)
```

and:

```
#the url at this point is https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3ARAIL&fstype=ii&ei=hGwhWNHVPOW7iwLMiIfIDA I've confirmed this with a print
url = driver.current_url
page3 = requests.get(url)
tree3 = html.fromstring(page3.content)
Cash_and_Short_Term_Investments = tree3.xpath('//*[@id="fs-table"]/tr[3]/td[2]/text()')
print('Cash_and_short_term_investments:', Cash_and_Short_Term_Investments)
```

I have removed the tbody from the XPath like some similar questions have suggested. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking questions like this, you need to provide a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem.

Looking at your second example, it is clear that the XPath expression you are using is incorrect. You are missing the `tbody` element from your XPath. (And you might like to select the correct table row by looking for the actual string you are searching.)

Given the following code:

```
from lxml import etree
import urllib

url="http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3ARAIL&fstype=ii&ei=hGwhWNHVPOW7iwLMiIfIDA"
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(urllib.urlopen(url), parser)
result = tree.xpath('//*[@id="fs-table"]/tbody/tr[normalize-space(td) = "Cash and Short Term Investments"]')
for x in result: print etree.tostring(x)
```

When running this like so:

```
> python test.py
```

You get the following output:

```
<tr>
<td class="lft lm">Cash and Short Term Investments
</td>
<td class="r">39.78</td>
<td class="r">78.45</td>
<td class="r">91.21</td>
<td class="r">110.02</td>
<td class="r rm">125.01</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="lft lm">Cash and Short Term Investments
</td>
<td class="r">110.02</td>
<td class="r">161.49</td>
<td class="r">184.49</td>
<td class="r rm">140.49</td>
</tr>
```

I'm sure you will be able to figure out what is wrong with your first example, once you turned it into a self-contained reproducer of the problem.

Comment: This is a good solution to get the strings, I then used Regex with regular expressions to isolate the numbers.